# Does iOS's WebView support HSTS?

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview

Does iOS WebView support HSTS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, iOS WebView supports HSTS See following link for more details: http://caniuse.com/#search=hsts